# `player.animate( [ {transform: "rotate(10)"`?

Tags: javascript, svg, web-animations, ecma

I'm trying to use **web animation/JS** (but not CSS!) to transform SVG.

I **can't** get the `transform: rotate(10)` to work--not sure why.

In the example `playerT` (scale) and `playerT3` (strokeWidth) are fine, **but** `playerT2` doesn't seem to do anything--why?

```
<svg width="400" height="400"  style="border:1px solid #00f"> 
<path id="triangle" d="M0,0L30,30L50,10z" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="3" />
<script type="text/ecmascript">
  <![CDATA[
var triangle=document.getElementById("triangle");
var playerT=triangle.animate(
    [{transform: 'scale(1)'},
     {transform: 'scale(5)'}],
      {duration:1000, delay:0,iterations: Infinity});

var playerT2=triangle.animate(
    [{transform: 'rotate(10)'},
     {transform: 'rotate(20)'}],
      {duration:1000, delay:0,iterations: Infinity});

var playerT3=triangle.animate(
    [{strokeWidth:3},
     {strokeWidth:0}],
      {duration:1000, delay:0,iterations: Infinity});
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

JSFiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/45cbhLqL/

PS: could I use a transformation matrix instead (if I have to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the unit in the rotate function (degrees, radians etc)
your code is working now : https://jsfiddle.net/45cbhLqL/1/

```
var playerT=triangle.animate(
    [{transform: 'rotate(10deg)'},
     {transform: 'rotate(20deg)'}],
      {duration:1000, delay:0,iterations: Infinity});
```